# How to remove accidentally committed files in git?

Tags: git

I forgot to add my git ignore file until a few changes in which caused my user & cache files to keep appearing in my git changes.

**Picture:**

[image]

How do I get these files to stop showing up in my changes history?

Comment: Why don't you want the .csproj file in the repository? I can agree about the .user file, that *probably* shouldn't have been committed, but the .csproj? You absolutely should commit that.

Comment: The `.csproj` should be tracked, it shouldn't be ignored.

Comment: Thee you go thats my mistake! So the csproj should be in there but how can I get rid of the user profile then? @LasseV.Karlsen

Comment: I had a similar issue. I fixed it in 2 steps. 
1 : Remove the file and commit the changes. 
2. Now add the file to git ignore.

Not sure if there is a better alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you'll want to keep the csproj file.

For the others, try this:

```
git rm MachineInspection.WebUI.csproj.user
git rm obj/Debug/DesightTimeResolveAssemblyReferencesInput.cache
```

... then commit and push.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to John's answer (`git rm`, [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm)), you might want to ignore all cache or compilation units.

For example, add to your `.gitignore` ([doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)):

```
obj/
```

to ignore the folder `obj` and its contents.

Answer (score -1):

If this is not public yet, and you don't mind loosing the history, you can

```
git reset <commit before wrong files entered>
... modify .gitignore to ignore these files
git add .
git commit -m "....."
```

This will reset the repository to the point before you added wrong files, without removing anything from your working directory, than, after you modify .gitignore you can add and commit. Unfortunately you loose all intermediate steps so you won't be able to go back to any of these if you need.