# Remove unintentionally commited file

Tags: git

Scenario:

I am on a feature/branch, modified several files and also added a new *temporary.file*. Unintentionally I commit and push all the changed files and also the new temporary one.

How to “uncommit” the temporary file?

What I did is

```
git rebase -i main
# change last commit to “edit”
# removed the temporary file
git add .
git rebase --continue
git push -f
```

What is a better way to do it? I lost the temporary file now, because I had to remove it. I suppose there should be a better way to handle such case.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67905982/how-to-remove-accidentally-committed-files-in-git

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of ways to approach this:

1. Simply remove the temporary file and commit and push a change that removes it.

   This leaves the mistake visible in the branch history, but a stray temp file most likely doesn't have a material affect on the project.
2. Amend and push the commit in which you accidentally added the temporary file.  Then reapply any later commits.

   The problem with is that when you amend a commit that you have published by pushing, you are potentially going to mess up things for other people who have pulled the changes.  This may or may not matter.

---

Note if the temp file contains secret information that is harmful to release, you will take more extreme steps to expunge it.  Neither of the above will expunge the secrets from the repository that you pushed it.

Answer (score 1):

[`git rm --cached <file>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm#Documentation/git-rm.txt---cached) removes the file from the index but not from the working tree. After that simply `git rebase --continue`.